# Find RC values of a second-order low-pass filter

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, transfer-function, low-pass, active-filter

I have a low-pass filter of second order.

[image]

The transfer function is:

$$\small G(s) = \frac{1}{R^2C^2s^2+(3CR - CR)s + 1}$$

And the amplitude function is:

$$\small A(s) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(R^2C^2s^2)^2 + ((3CR - CR)s)^2 + 1}}$$

If I say that A(s) = 0.25 at s = 2·π·90 rad/s, I can select C = 2.7160e-06 F and R = 1000 Ω to achieve A(s) = 0.25 at s = 2·π·90 rad/s.

My transfer function will look like this then:

$$\small G(2) = \frac{1}{7.3767\cdot 10^{-6}s^2 + 0.005432s + 1}$$

But when I analyse with a Bode diagram, I get -10.526 dB, which is about 0.29.

Is the transfer function of this model correct? This question is an extenstion to this question: [Transfer function of second-order Butterworth filter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/634172/transfer-function-of-second-order-butterworth-filter)

[image]

Comment: What is `3*C*R - C*R`?

Comment: @Andyaka It will become a value?

Comment: What is `3x - x`?

Comment: In other words, either there is an error somewhere in your formula or, you are not simplifying things.

Comment: Oh, it will be 2CR. I'm using symbolic math

Comment: Feel free to update your question.

Comment: @Heretic Look at [this site](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/Fkeisan.htm). Also, what you're showing here and what you showed in your [previous answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/634172/95619) are different circuits. Not lastly, it's not enough to impose a certain gain at a certain frequency: you need to impose passband ripple/attenuation, corner frequency, attenuation at fc, stopband and attenuation in the stopband. A Butterworth is defined by three parameters: fc+fs+As or fc+Ap+fs. Or a minimum of N+fc, when fs+As are resulting from it.

Comment: @Heretic You can't get a Butterworth if you keep the resistors at the same value and the two capacitors at the same value. Can't happen. You have to give up something. For example, allow the feedback capacitor to be twice the value of the grounded capacitor. See additions to my prior answer to you.

Comment: @jonk do you have a table how to select to get a specific filter such as Butterworth or chevby chef or Bessel?

Comment: @Heretic No. I don't use tables. I use SymPy to perform the computations, directly. And Chebyshev comes in a wide variety. So there's not only one kind of those.

Comment: @jonk write an answer how to select the RC values using sympy.

Comment: @Heretic Done below.

Comment: \$s\rightarrow \omega\$ won't work. It must be \$s\rightarrow j\omega\$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the two Rs equal to each other and the two Cs equal to each other (and unity gain) that filter is not a Butterworth filter. It is what Horowitz and Hill refer to as a "benign" filter.

That filter has 2 identical real poles placed at the same place (coincident poles) on the S-plane's real axis.

Q = 0.5, damping ratio (zeta) = 1 giving critical damping.

The magnitude response will be down 6 dB at angular frequency, w = 1/(RC).

There are two ways to convert that filter into a Butterworth filter:-

1. Make the feedback capacitor twice the value of the other capacitor (let's now call the feedback capacitor 2C) in which case the cut-off frequency (-3 dB frequency) becomes

[image: Equation]

2. Keep the two Rs equal to each other and the two Cs equal to each other and add a couple of resistors around the op amp to give the filter a gain of 1.586. In this configuration the cut-off frequency (-3 dB frequency) becomes

[image: Equation]

This configuration is known as an equal value filter.

In either case the poles have become a complex conjugate pair with the damping ratio equal to the Q which is equal to 1/(sqrt(2)) = 0.7071

Comment: Very nicely said!! See bottom of my earlier post [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/634193/38098) that says the same thing to the OP. +1!!

Answer (score 2):

Using SymPy, you can find the following for your schematic:

```
var('r r1 r2 c1 c2 s v1 v2 iout vout vin')
eq1 = Eq( v1/r1 + v1/r2 + v1/(1/s/c2), vin/r1 + v2/r2 + vout/(1/s/c2) )  # KCL v1
eq2 = Eq( v2/(1/s/c1) + v2/r2, v1/r2 )                                   # KCL v2
eq3 = Eq( vout/(1/s/c2), iout + v1/(1/s/c2) )                            # KCL Vout
eq4 = Eq( vout, v2 )                                                # opamp (-)=(+)
ans = tf2( solve( [ eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4 ], [ iout, v1, v2, vout ] )
eq5 = Eq( ans[zeta]*2, sqrt(2) )                          # Butterworth requirement
solve( eq5, [ c1, c2 ] )[0][0].subs( { r1:r, r2:r } )     # find c1 in terms of c2
c2/2
```

That tells me that \$C_2=2\,C_1\$ for a Butterworth given that \$R_1=R_2=R\$ and with a gain \$K=1\$.

The code for **tf2** can be found [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/570978/38098).

I highly recommend becoming proficient in Python and SymPy.

Comment: By the way. It works very well to say that both C1 and C2 is equal. Even if it's not a butterworth filter. For me, I'm intrested in pressing down the amplitude of the noise.

Comment: @Heretic You want to be very precise about what you want to achieve. "Pressing down the noise" isn't precise. There's \$\frac1{f}\$ (pink) noise near the DC region for any opamp (choppers are another thing altogether, though.) There's white noise beyond that. Sources include shot noise, Johnson noise, kT/C (same as Johnson noise but for caps), ... What you design should be tailored carefully for what noise you are accepting at the first stage. And the first stage itself should be carefully crafted for the sensor. There's a lot of art here.

Comment: @Heretic After the 1st stage, once you have let the S/N sensor situation arrive electronically, mostly all you can do later on is trade off bandwidth for S/N. All the important stuff happens *before* the sensor and *at* the sensor transducer stage, itself. For example, using optical filters to limit the wavelengths of light that arrive at an optical sensor *before* it generates an electronic signal. Stuff like that.

Comment: What I want to achieve is that at some frequency, I want that amplitude to be X as small e.g 0.25 smaller than before. That's my goal. And I don't care if the filter is a bessel, butterworth or chebychev. It's still a second order filter.

Comment: @Heretic That's probably a different question where we'd (I'd) need a lot more detail about the circumstances and the goals. Not just a comment. In any case, I've provided what you asked -- SymPy code. (No, I don't expect to be selected for that little bit. I'm just saying I've answered your question in comments above.)

Comment: Yes. I understand. Very good answer. I like it :) I'm am a beginner in filtering and right now I want to achieve the goal to "pressing down" the amplitude at a specific frequency. It works for me. The question is about finding R and C and my misstake was the amplitude function. It's wrong. It should be as Jan Eerland wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Well, working from [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/634172/transfer-function-of-second-order-butterworth-filter/634175#634175) answer we can see that your transfer function leads to:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right)&=\lim_{\substack{\text{R}_4\space\to\space0\\\text{R}_6\space\to\space\infty}}\frac{\text{R}_4+\text{R}_6}{\text{C}\text{C}\text{R}\text{R}\text{R}_6\text{s}^2+\left(\text{C}\text{R}_6\left(\text{R}+\text{R}\right)-\text{C}\text{R}\text{R}_4\right)\text{s}+\text{R}_6}\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{\left(\text{CRs}\right)^2+2\text{CRs}+1}
\end{split}\tag1
\end{equation}

So, we get:

$$\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(1-\left(\text{CR}\omega\right)^2\right)^2+\left(2\text{CR}\omega\right)^2}}\tag2$$

And if you want \$\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\cdot2\pi\cdot90\right)\right|=\frac{1}{4}\$ you can choose \$\text{R}\$ and solve for \$\text{C}\$:

$$\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(1-\left(\text{CR}\cdot2\pi\cdot90\right)^2\right)^2+\left(2\text{CR}\cdot2\pi\cdot90\right)^2}}\space\implies\space\text{C}=\frac{1}{60\pi\sqrt{3}\text{R}}\tag3$$

Substituting \$(3)\$ into \$(2)\$ gives:

$$\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{10800\pi^2}{10800\pi^2+\omega^2}\tag4$$

So at \$\omega=2\pi\cdot90\space\text{rad/sec}\$ we get:

$$20\log_{10}\left(\frac{10800\pi^2}{10800\pi^2+\left(2\pi\cdot90\right)^2}\right)=-20\log_{10}\left(4\right)\approx-12.0412\space\text{dB}\tag5$$

---

In general \$0<\text{n}<1\$:

$$\text{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(1-\left(\text{CR}\omega_0\right)^2\right)^2+\left(2\text{CR}\omega_0\right)^2}}\space\implies\space\text{C}=\frac{1}{\text{R}\omega_0}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{1}{\text{n}}-1}\tag6$$

So, we get:

$$\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{\text{n}\omega_0^2}{\left(1-\text{n}\right)\omega^2+\text{n}\omega_0^2}\tag7$$

Comment: I like your answer. I will study it.

Comment: Jan your answer is based on a sallen key filter with gain (a different circuit). That is not what the question asks for.

Comment: @Heretic thanks! Take a look at my edit.

Comment: Jan! Your math is correct, but why does my bodediagram not show the correct db Gain?

Comment: @Heretic have you plot \$20\log_{10}\left(\text{transfer function}\right)\$?

Comment: @JanEerland Yes. I first solve `CR` from `A == sqrt(K^2)/sqrt((CR^2*s^2)^2 + ((3*CR - CR*K)*s)^2 + 1^2)` using `symbolic` in GNU Octave. I select `R = 1000, A = 0.25, K = 1` and then found out that `C = 2.7160e-06 ` F

Comment: @Heretic when you used \$\text{s}=2\pi\cdot90\$, I found \$\text{C}\approx1.21116\cdot10^{-11}\$.

Comment: @JanEerland So this equation  `A == sqrt(K^2)/sqrt((CR^2*s^2)^2 + ((3*CR - CR*K)*s)^2 + 1^2)` will be different values of `CR` if I try to solve it with `A = 0.25, K = 1, s = 2*pi*90` ?